# Tag Synonym Suggestion

Tags: support

Recent new tags of [bov](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bov) and [blow-off-valve](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blow-off-valve) are synonyms. Not sure which way this should be moved, but we don't need both.

(PS: I hate that I have to have so many points in a tag in order to suggest synonyms directly, lol! Oh, well ... it is what it is.)

Comment: Regarding the threshold for synonym suggestions: [Improving tag synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244) on Meta.SE

Comment: @JoshCaswell ... I'm glad they are at least thinking about the problems with tag synonyms, though I didn't see where they are addressing my particular "issue" of having to have so many points in a tag to even suggest a synonyms. Anyway, good post, if not long winded.

Comment: I may have linked to the wrong one, then, @Paulster. There's a couple with discussions of the problems.

Answer (score 3):

I prefer [blow-off-valve](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blow-off-valve) as the primary.  Acronyms are scary to normal people.

Comment: Works for me ... just don't see as how we need both :D